# Unwanted Blockiness/Low-Poly Problems

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, sculpting

While I was sculpting a dragon model, I found the wings were developing with very low poly counts, and didn't look smooth. As I tried to grab the edges of the wings to improve its shape, I found it simply wouldn't stretch. I figured the system is "confused", for lack of a better word, because the wings are thin and flat, while the other body parts are much thicker. I therefore tried to thicken the wings by using draw, but that had barely any effect, until it had none at all. I'm getting the impression there's an upper polygon limit with the setup I'm using. (I believe it's the default, except for setting autosmooth to 180c and various symmetry toggles during the process) I had expanded the model somewhat prior to starting on the wings, to provide sufficient room to later work on the fine details of the toes. (which are undeveloped right now)

I have already closed and re-opened Blender.

I came over to Blender from the much simpler interface of Sculptris, so instructions with a minimum of window-checking and setting-toggling that allow for a uniform clay-like look throughout the process are preferred.

As you can see below, the chest, tail, and most of the legs are properly high-resolution, while the wings are a low-poly mess.

[image: In-progress model of a dragon on Sculptris. The wings are obviously blocky and low-poly.]

EDIT: Topology, as seen in edit mode. It is obvious the wings don't have the same level of detail as the rest of the body.

[image: Wireframe of a dragon sculpture on GIMP. The body is highly detailed, but the wings are low-poly.]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add images in edit mode that show the topology of the object.

Comment: Do you have any modifiers (mulltires, etc) on the object? Are you using dynotopo, or remesh sculpt? Or you attempting to sculpt with only the topology of the object as is?

Comment: I don't think I'm using any multipliers. I am only sculpting using the sculpt mode.